# How to show nested array with blade in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I try to show nested array with blade in Laravel 5.1 but I can't do this :

**Controller:**

```
public function track($id){
  $tracks = track::with('trials.samples')->where('trials_id',$id)->get();

  //return $tracks;
  return view('Tracks.index',compact('tracks'));
}
```

**Traks.index:**

```
{{ $track['samples']['variety'] }}
```

**return $tracks return:**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "trials_id": 1,
    "date": "2015-12-16",
    "comments": "\u0646\u062a\u06cc\u062c\u0647 \u062e\u0627\u0635\u06cc \u0646\u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0647 !",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "trials": {
        "id": 1,
        "persons_id": 1,
        "samples_id": 1,
        "amount": "125000",
        "date": "2015-12-09",
        "comments": "",
        "code": "5CEPY",
        "created_at": "2015-12-08 06:46:58",
        "updated_at": "2015-12-08 06:46:58",
        "samples": {
            "id": 1,
            "variety": "keyhan",
            "supplier_id": 1,
            "lot_number": "2550",
            "date": "2015-12-11",
            "amount": 125000,
            "unit_id": 1,
            "technical_fact": "\u0641\u0646\u06cc",
            "comments": "1",
            "file_address": "",
            "category_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-12-08 06:46:34",
            "updated_at": "2015-12-08 06:46:34"
        }
    }
}]
```

I tried this code too, but nothing is showing:

```
{{ $track['trials.samples']['variety'] }} 
{{ $track->samples['variety'] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I've never used `compact()` to return anything to a view, so I am unfamiliar with it's usage.

However, you can use `with()` to return stuff to a view, so if you change that line to:

```
return view('Tracks.index')->with(["tracks" => $tracks]);
```

You can then show them in the blade using a `@foreach` loop, or accessing the first element using `$tracks[0]...`. For example:

```
@foreach($tracks AS $track)
  {{ $track->comments }}
  @foreach($track->trials AS $trial)
    {{ $trial->code }}
    @foreach($trial->samples AS $sample)
      {{ $sample->variety }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Note, this depends on how your relationships are set up in your `Track`, `Trial` and `Sample` models. For example:

```
public function trials(){
  return $this->hasMany("App\Trial")->get();
  // vs 
  return $this->hasOne("App\Trial")->first();
}
```

In the event of `->get()`, you would have to use the `@foreach` syntax to access it, but if you were only expecting one result you could simply use:

```
{{ $track->trials->samples->variety }}
```

If you need more information, check out Laravel's documentation: [Blade Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) and [Eloquent Collections](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections)

Comment: I get this error with above code:Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\Aghapesae\Desktop\sampling-style\resources\views\Tracks\index.blade.php)